# My Spring Cloud Config server is working well, however it is continuously complaining about an invalid argument "--spring.config.location="

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I created a new Spring Cloud Config server with SpringBoot 1.5.21.RELEASE and Spring Cloud Config "1.4.7.RELEASE". Building and running with Java 8.
It is configured with a 'native' profile so it is using the file system as backend repository.
My config server is starting properly and can accept all client requests as expected. I have few SpringBoot apps that connect to it and can properly fetch their configuration properties for various profiles and labels. So it is apparently working perfectly very well from client point of view!

However, when looking closely at the log files of the config server, we can see plenty of errors complaining about the an "Invalid Argument syntax: --spring.config.location=" during each refresh and for every client request.

We can also see that the health status of the Config Server is 'down' for the same reason.

I usually do not explicitly define the property "spring.config.location" since the default value is always fine to me.
In this case, I tried to explicitly override that property with the location where the configuration files of the Config Server are located. I tried to override the value in bootstrap.properties as well as at command line and even with environment variable, but it does not fix anything.
Like for all of my other SpringBoot app, my config location is located under standard "file:./config" folder (and also under "classpath:/").

I also have some dependencies and config to connect my Config Server onto a SpringBoot Admin server, but even when I disable that, I'm still getting same error/behavior. I was wondering that maybe this could be the cause of the problem. 
Otherwise the Config Server is a perfectly normal and standard SpringBoot app like all the other ones I created and deployed in my infrastructure. Up to now, each SprintBoot app had their own set of properties files under the standard location (./config), but I'm now trying to work with a config server instead.

Here is the content of the bootstrap.properties file of the Config Server:

```
spring.config.name=config-server
spring.config.location=classpath:/,classpath:/config/,file:./,file:./config/
```

And below are some of the properties defined in the "./config/config-server.properties" file:

```
spring.profiles.active=native

spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=false
spring.cloud.config.server.native.addLabelLocations=false
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=file:./config/repo/{label}/{application},file:./config/repo/{label}

app.name=Config Server
app.artifactId=config-server

spring.application.name=${app.name}
spring.application.admin.enabled=true
spring.application.admin.jmx-name=org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication

spring.main.sources=com.mycompany.packagepath.Application



server.display-name=${app.name}

server.port=10700
server.servlet-path=/
server.context-path=/


management.port=10701
management.security.enabled=false
management.context-path=/manage
management.security.roles=managers
management.info.defaults.enabled=true
management.info.build.enabled=true
management.info.env.enabled=true
management.info.git.enabled=true
management.info.git.mode=full


server.tomcat.accept-count=50
server.tomcat.max-connections=50
server.tomcat.max-threads=10
server.tomcat.min-spare-threads=2
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true


logging.config=config/logback-spring.xml
## Path were to send output log files by default.
logging.path=logs
## Default log level.
logging.level.root=DEBUG

spring.jmx.enabled=true

endpoints.enabled=true
endpoints.sensitive=false
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
endpoints.shutdown.path=/shutdown
endpoints.shutdown.sensitive=false
endpoints.trace.enabled=false

endpoints.jmx.enabled=true
endpoints.jmx.domain=agentservice
endpoints.jmx.unique-names=true


security.basic.enabled=true
security.basic.realm=Spring
security.basic.path=/**
security.basic.authorize-mode=role
security.ignored=
security.require-ssl=false
security.sessions=stateless
security.user.name=user
security.user.password=user
security.user.role=USER
```

This is the errors I can see in log file:

```
2019-06-25 18:25:15.443 +0000 DEBUG         [             registrationTask1] [sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection:61        ] -  sun.net.www.MessageHeader@f573b447 pairs: {POST /api/applications HTTP/1.1: null}{Accept: application/json}{Content-Type: application/json}{User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_191}{Host: configserverhost:10710}{Connection: keep-alive}{Content-Length: 208}
2019-06-25 18:25:15.444 +0000 DEBUG         [             registrationTask1] [sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection:61        ] -  sun.net.www.MessageHeader@31a304286 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 201}{X-Application-Context: Admin Server Application:dev:10710}{Location: http://devrhm8.dev.emergis:10710/ab2b05fc}{Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8}{Transfer-Encoding: chunked}{Date: Tue, 25 Jun 2019 18:25:15 GMT}
2019-06-25 18:25:15.445 +0000 DEBUG         [             registrationTask1] [d.c.b.a.client.registration.ApplicationRegistrator:75 ] -  Application refreshed itself as ab2b05fc
2019-06-25 18:25:16.551 +0000 ERROR         [         http-nio-10701-exec-3] [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication:771        ] -  Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid argument syntax: --spring.config.location=
        at org.springframework.core.env.SimpleCommandLineArgsParser.parse(SimpleCommandLineArgsParser.java:75)
        at org.springframework.core.env.SimpleCommandLinePropertySource.<init>(SimpleCommandLinePropertySource.java:89)
        at org.springframework.boot.DefaultApplicationArguments$Source.<init>(DefaultApplicationArguments.java:76)
        at org.springframework.boot.DefaultApplicationArguments.<init>(DefaultApplicationArguments.java:42)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:294)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NativeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(NativeEnvironmentRepository.java:134)
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.CompositeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(CompositeEnvironmentRepository.java:45)
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.ConfigServerHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(ConfigServerHealthIndicator.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:43)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:68)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.HealthEndpoint.invoke(HealthEndpoint.java:86)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.getCurrentHealth(HealthMvcEndpoint.java:178)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.getHealth(HealthMvcEndpoint.java:167)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(HealthMvcEndpoint.java:144)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:854)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:765)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcChildContextConfiguration$CompositeHandlerAdapter.handle(EndpointWebMvcChildContextConfiguration.java:288)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I think it has to do with `spring.config.name=config-server` + `spring.config.location` and the native profile. The error is coming from `ConfigServerHealthIndicator`. You could try disabling that.

Comment: Thank you, you were right, it removed the error. The health status of the config server is now green. However it does not explain why I was getting this bad health indicator status in the server. If you could find the exact source of the problem, it would be better I think. Would be nice to be able to keep this health check indicator enabled in the config server.

Comment: It doesn't know what to check because of the placeholders